# develop with notepad and run in python, or use Interactive Python?

Tags: python, interactive

I use python as follows...
notepad++ is on left of screen.
Black command prompt is on right of screen.
I write my python prog in notepad and save it to dir python as ggg.py ,then using (control S).
I switch to command prompt screen and run it.
Any errors I go back and fix and run again.
Could it be that using the python with the >>> prompt is more efficient.ie How can I duplicate
the above using interactive python(>>>)? Is it easier than my current method?
acorn.

Comment: You could use an IDE. Most run the code and show you the lines with errors automatically.

Comment: Learn to use an IDE. Download and use Eclipse. Then you can add python by download a plugin called pydev. Then you have a great editor together with a debugger.

Comment: You don't need to use an IDE. You might want to start playing with other editors (vim) if you want to be able to jump to class/function definitions. You can use the interactive Python shell to quickly test out ideas. I personally use IPython a lot because it lets me tab complete objects. A great way to play with an unfamiliar API.

Comment: Another nice way to do many things is ipython's [notebook mode](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html). I often initially write code in there and then copy it into a regular file when it's more-or-less done.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you give IPython a try. It is an advanced interactive programming environment for python. Inside Ipython you could use the magic command %edit to open an external editor like Notepad++ to type your code, and then execute the code in IPython. Or you can type %run to load your script to IPython. There are a lot other magic commands to help you improve your efficiency.

You can also try IPython's new feature notebook.